# How to check when a user clicks a specific button in a browser control?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a win-form that contains a browser and It contains a website designed by a client of mine.

It has an end event that when clicked is supposed to close the browser but this doesn't work with Visual studio browser control.

I am trying to see if there is a way that I can be notified when the user clicks a specific button within the browser. I know what the element is called but i cant figure out how i get notified if its clicked.

Any help will be well received.

Comment: Just to be clear the reason for this is due to the javascript event window.close() not being picked up by the browser control.